# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'getCities' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, runtime-error, radcombobox

I am Using RadComboBox In UserControll I Want To Bind All The Cities With the CheckBoxes In RadComboBox. For That I Have Written Code As Follows :

FOR ASPX :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getItemCheckBox(item) {
    debugger;
    //Get the 'div' representing the current RadComboBox Item.
    var itemDiv = item.get_element();

    //Get the collection of all 'input' elements in the 'div' (which are contained in the Item).
    var inputs = itemDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < inputs.length; inputIndex++) {
        var input = inputs[inputIndex];

        //Check the type of the current 'input' element.
        if (input.type == "checkbox") {
            return input;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
function check() {
    debugger;
    alert("hello");
}
function getCities() {

    var combo = $find("<%= cmbCity.ClientID %>");
    var hdnAddressType = document.getElementById("<%= hfGeoLocation.ClientID %>");
    var items = combo.get_items();
    var selectedItemsTexts = "";
    var selectedItemsValues = "";
    var itemsCount = items.get_count();
    for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < itemsCount; itemIndex++) {
        var item = items.getItem(itemIndex);

        var checkbox = getItemCheckBox(item);

        //Check whether the Item's CheckBox) is checked.
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            selectedItemsTexts += item.get_text() + ", ";
            selectedItemsValues += item.get_value() + ",";
        }
    }

    hdnAddressType.value = selectedItemsValues;

    selectedItemsTexts = selectedItemsTexts.substring(0, selectedItemsTexts.length - 2);
    selectedItemsValues = selectedItemsValues.substring(0, selectedItemsValues.length - 2);

    //Set the text of the RadComboBox with the texts of the selected Items, separated by ','.
    combo.set_text(selectedItemsTexts);

    //Set the comboValue hidden field value with values of the selected Items, separated by ','.
    combo.set_value(selectedItemsValues);

    //Clear the selection that RadComboBox has made internally.
    if (selectedItemsValues == "") {
        combo.clearSelection();
    }
}
</script>

<div>
      <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbCity" runat="server" Height="200px" ExpandDirection="Up"
                    Width="130px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div id="chk">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCity" runat="server" onclick="getCities();" Text='<%#Eval("CityName")%>' />
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
     </telerik:RadComboBox>
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGeoLocation" runat="server" />
</div>
```

And In Code Behind. Following Code:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<usp_SelectCmbCityResult> lstCity = null;
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lstCity = new CityDomain().SelectCmbCity();
        cmbCity.DataSource = lstCity;
        cmbCity.DataValueField = "CityName";
        cmbCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
        cmbCity.DataBind();
        MenUs.Common.Common.BindRadioButtonList(ref rbtnOrientation, typeof(MenUs.Common.Enums.Orientation));
        MenUs.Common.Common.BindRadioButtonList(ref rbtnTargetGender, typeof(MenUs.Common.Enums.TargetGender));
        MenUs.Common.Common.BindRadioButtonList(ref rbtnTargetMarital, typeof(MenUs.Common.Enums.TargetMaritalStatus));
    }
}
```

When I Click/CheckBox I am Gettig Error

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'getCities' is undefined**

Please Tell me What's Wrong ??
Thanks In Advance.....

---

Problem Solved. Actually Problem Was In MasterPage That's Why This Error Was Generated.
Thanks All For The Support....

Comment: Do you get this error in IIS or ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: @ Răzvan Panda : On ASP.NET Development Server Sir

Comment: The script tag is closed in your code right?

Comment: And do you use a ScriptManager on the page?

Comment: @Răzvan Panda : Ya sir Scropt tag is closed And am not using script manager.But The Page Which Will Contain This UserControll,It's MAsterPage is Containing RadScriptManager.

Comment: See if this might help you: http://encosia.com/updated-your-webconfig-but-sys-is-still-undefined/

Comment: @Răzvan Panda Thnx but My Scenario Is Different then this link mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to see the Javascript code as the browser sees it, rather than with the embedded ASP tags.

These ASP tags should be converted into strings; I suspect the problem is likely to be one of these strings. I don't know what the values of `cmbCity.ClientID` or `hfGeoLocation.ClientID` are, but it is possible that they are causing the code to break. If they contain quote marks or line feeds, then your Javascript code will be invalid.

You should use the browser's View Source feature to see at how code looks to the browser. This is likely to show you what the problem is.